# How to update a react state with multiple values and relying on that updated state with a callback function. Will it work?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I'm trying to update the state of an object `post`. The values should come from the form fields `title` and `entry`, the states of which are setting in real-time, correctly. Is this not the correct way to invoke the `setState` callback function? The asynchronous part of updating the state is where I think the problem lies, but I don't have enough familiarity with JS to really see what's going on here. Any help would be appreciated.

```
class EditForm extends React.Component {
 initialState = {
 title: (this.props.posts.find(el => el.id === this.props.id)).title,
 entry: (this.props.posts.find(el => el.id === this.props.id)).entry,
 post: this.props.posts.find(el => el.id === this.props.id)
}

state = {...this.initialState}

handleChange = (e) => {
 const { name, value } = e.target
 this.setState({ [name]: value })
}

handleSubmit = (e) => {
 e.preventDefault()
 this.setState(prevState => ({
  post: {
      ...prevState.post,
      title: this.state.title,
      entry: this.state.entry
  }
}), this.nowSubmit())
}

nowSubmit = () => {
 console.log(this.state.post)
 this.props.dispatch(updatePost(this.state.post))
 this.props.closeForm()
}
```

Comment: So, is this component connected to the store and getting the `post` back from there again and set the local state?

Comment: Yes. I'm guessing this is probably not best practice, but I'm just trying to get this thing to work. However I'm totally open to changing it.

Comment: However, when I pass in the post to dispatch, the redux function is just grabbing the id off the object, so it should work. Actually, now that I think about it, that might not work.

Comment: Since I don't know the whole structure of your app I can't see anything exactly but since you have the `posts` prop from your store, then you can use it without the local state. Ok, you need `title` and `entry`, since you want to show those in some inputs probably. But, you don't need the `post` prop to be in the local state. In `handleSubmit` function you can grab the `post` from your props and recreate it by updating with `title` and `entry` from the local state. Then you can pass it to your dispatcher function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are almost there but just have the incorrect callback :)

If you try something along the lines of:

```
this.setState(prevState => {
    return {
        post: {*variables*}
    }
}, this.nowSubmit)
```

Or alternatively just put the simple function in there as `() => {this.nowSubmit function}` as long as it's short :)

This is the same as when you have to bind a function in the constructor if you want to use it inline. If you want more details on why let me know :)

Comment: So why did I need to remove the parenthesis from the `this.nowSubmit()`? It does work without them!

Comment: I'm super tired at the moment so this is going to be a bad explanation, but simply because of the way JS works when you write it that way the function is invoked on load, instead of waiting for the actual callback.

You can either bind a function with the current `this` context in the constructor, or use fat arrows to do this automatically... Then on load it knows to wait when you remove the parenthesis

Reading this back hurts but I can't articulate it any better right now, have a google :P

http://egorsmirnov.me/2015/08/16/react-and-es6-part3.html

Comment: And if you can updoot the answer as correct so everyone knows that'd be awesome :)

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate the explanation!